# Getting changesets between specific builds

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am trying to get all of the work items between two builds. I can see only one way to make this work done - get the start and end changesets and get the work item for each.
The problem I have, is to get to the set of changesets from the build number.
I have tried using the get associated changesets but this doesn't work as it only get the changesets for that build and not ones before it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It looks like an answer was provided to this exact question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821734/show-all-changesets-between-two-labels.

Answer (score 3):

This code will get all the changesets between two labels:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the first build label:");
var firstVersion = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter second build label:");
var secondVersion = Console.ReadLine();

var server = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("TFS SERVER INSTANCE"));
var hyperlinker = server.GetService<TswaClientHyperlinkService>();

var versionService = server.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var changesets = versionService.QueryHistory(@"$/EntDev", VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, null,
                       VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec("L" + firstVersion, null), 
                       VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec("L" + secondVersion, null), 
                       Int32.MaxValue, 
                       false, 
                       false);
var workItems = new List<WorkItem>();
foreach (Changeset changeset in changesets)
{
  var link = hyperlinker.GetChangesetDetailsUrl(changeset.ChangesetId);
  Console.WriteLine("#" + changeset.ChangesetId.ToString() + " - " + changeset.Comment + " - " + link.ToString());

  workItems.AddRange(changeset.WorkItems);
}
foreach (var item in workItems)
{
  var link = hyperlinker.GetWorkItemEditorUrl(item.Id);
  Console.WriteLine("WI#" + item.Id + " - " + item.Title + " - " + link.ToString());
}
Console.ReadLine();
```