# View Changes To Files From Previous Labels

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, project-management

We are using Visual Studio 2010 and before each release to our test server we apply a label to that version.  I have been tasked with doing a security review of all code changes before each release.  So instead of asking each team member to send me a list of files they have touched, I was wondering if there is a way to view a history of changes per label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using TFS 2010, you can see the changes between 2 labels like this:

```
tf.exe history /server:http://tfs:8080 "$/ProjectName/src" /version:LMain-CI_20100831.6~LMain-CI_20100927.1 /recursive /noprompt /brief
```

(taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3822341/61697))

Comment: thanks demon, I'm in the process of getting the server info and then I'll try it out. I'll let you know if it work. Thanks again.

Comment: I found another way to view the changes. In source control, if you right click on the folder with the labels applied to it and select View History the history window will have a labels tab at the top. Select it and find the label you want to compare against. Right click it and select compare, this will show you a Folder Difference window.  I guess both are solutions, which ever you prefer.