# Associating changesets and workitems with previous baseline build of specific quality

Tags: tfs

In the default workflow for TFS 2010, the Changesets and WorkItems that are associated with the current build are the delta from the previously successful build and are included in the build summary.

My client's requirements are a bit different. They need the baseline to be the most recent build whose Build Quality has been set to a particular value, e.g. "Released". So each build in the current iteration would then include a complete growing list of changes from that previous release.

This info can be extracted after the build using a script, similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821734/show-all-changesets-between-two-labels), but we need it to be included in the build summary.

Has anyone encountered a similar requirement?

I assume the workflow needs modification to detect the previous "Released" build, but am a bit lost at how to include this.

Answer (score 0):

If a manual tool is ok then this might work for you.  It doesn't associate work items to builds, but it trawls through builds combining all the work items associated until the last build of quality X.

http://gertgregers.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/build-release-notes/ - No Source or download

**Edit**

Here's a walkthrough to edit a build definition, however it still leaves a lot of the implementation up to you

http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/04/15/implementing-release-notes-in-tfs-team-build-2010.aspx

Comment: There are some pictures, but there's no actual tool to download. The CodePlex project is a library *used* by the custom activity that Gert describes.

Comment: well that's embarrasing, it actually looked kind of ok in the screenshots =(

Comment: @devstuff How about this one? http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/04/15/implementing-release-notes-in-tfs-team-build-2010.aspx

Comment: Alternatively you could use something like TFS Deployer to catch build quality changes and write a custom powershell script to find all the builds since the last one of that quality and associate work items from each to the current one.