# How to find changesets between two TFS labels (for Release Notes / Change log)

Tags: tfs, msbuild, release, tfsbuild

I want to produce release notes to show the changes that have occurred between two different TFS builds.  Our builds automatically label the version used to produce the build.

I've familiar with the **tf hist** command and have seen the advice in [Show all changesets between two labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821734/show-all-changesets-between-two-labels). I've seen the accepted answers advice to use the command using dates instead of lables. Understood.

I acutally really like the output when running (dumping the detailed results to a text file):

```
D:\workspace>tf hist . /recursive  /version:D11/20/2014~D07/24/2014 /noprompt /format:Detailed > hist.txt
```

However, if I use labels for the /version parameter, I never am able to see changeset results... labels

```
D:\workspace>tf hist . /recursive /version:LMyLabelA~LMyLabelB
```

[image]

...but lots of labels:

[image]

1. What are the reason that my tf hist command is not showing changesets when using labels for the /version?
2. Is there another approach that I should try?

EDIT:
I've seen some additional Q&A that doesn't quite address my issue:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8fa9ec63-316a-4ad7-a919-5afd86da87ad/missing-changeset-when-tf-history-by-label-range?forum=tfsversioncontrol

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5efbf54f-ac46-4569-973d-592adefa7e37/get-list-of-files-changed-after-a-specific-label?forum=tfsversioncontrol

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/bc9328c2-f73f-4d41-b8f7-0a196a7fe7de/odd-output-from-tf-hist-using-a-label-in-version-spec?forum=tfsversioncontrol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using tf hist incorrectly.

The key is the ordering of the labels in /version.  The following works fine, assuming that LabelA was applied before LabelB.

```
D:\workspace>tf hist . /recursive /version:LMyLabelA~LMyLabelB
```

Unfortunately the command I was running was:

```
D:\workspace>tf hist . /recursive /version:LMyLabelB~LMyLabelA
```